# List rows by count when some rows refer to another row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-server-2014

I'm attempting to write a query that will list items from Table 2 in order of how many rows reference it in Table 1. The difficulty is that some rows in Table 2 are actually based on another row in Table 2, in which case the row it refers to should be counted instead.

My structure looks like this:

**Table 1**

```
itemID         templateID

1              1
2              2
3              3
4              4
5              5
```

**Table 2**

```
templateName   templateID   basedOnTemplateID

Foo            1            null
Bar            2            null
Tree           3            1
Dog            4            2
Bird           5            null
```

**Desired Results**

```
templateName   templateID   itemCount

Foo            1            2
Bar            2            2
Bird           5            1
Tree           3            0
Dog            4            0
```

What I have so far:

```
SELECT TOP (5) 
    Max(table2.templateName) 'templateName', 
    Max(table2.templateID) 'templateID', 
    Count([itemID]) 'itemCount'
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN
    table2 on table1.templateid = (
         CASE 
              WHEN table2.basedOnTemplateID is not null 
              THEN table2.basedOnTemplateID 
              ELSE table2.templateID 
         END)
GROUP BY table2.templateid 
ORDER BY Count(itemID) DESC
```

Comment: Aside: You might want to use [`coalesce`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead of your `case` expression: `table1.templateid = coalesce( table2.basedOnTemplateID, table2.templateID )`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

You can `left join` and aggregate as follows:

```
select
    t2.templateName,
    t2.templateID,
    count(t1.templateID) itemCount
from table2 t2
left join table1 t1 
    on  t1.templateID = t2.templateID 
    and t2.basedOnTemplateID is null
group by t2.templateName, t2.templateID
order by itemCount desc, t2.templateID
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This approach seems to be excluding rows from t2 where the value of `basedOnTemplateID` is null though. Instead of omitting it, I need it to join the row that it references.